# PHP Trait call inherited function

Tags: php, inheritance, traits

I have got a trait

```
trait Foo{

    protected static function foo(){
        echo 'Hello';
    }
}
```

and a class

```
class Bar{
    use Foo;

    private static function foo(){
        Foo::foo();

        echo ' World!';
    }
}
```

I cannot use `Foo:foo()`. What can I do to achieve the desired effect?

**EDIT**

Using

```
use Foo {foo as parentFoo}

private static function foo(){

    self::parentFoo();

    echo ' World!';

}
```

did the trick.

Comment: see conflict resolution http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.traits.php

Comment: Psst, you're trying to call a non-static method in a static way. You should be seeing a warning about that.  Maybe you should turn your `error_reporting` level up.

Comment: Oh, oops, I forgot to add the static keywords in the description. They are both static in reality. – @rambocoder: Thanks, see edit. It did the trick.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
class Bar{

    use Foo {
        Foo::foo as foofoo;
    }

    private static function foo(){

        self::foofoo();

        echo ' World!';

    }

}
```

Comment: Yep, exactly, except for the semicolon position and the static keyword ;) Thanks.

Comment: Yes, didn't see the change in the question to `static`.

Answer (score 0):

Are you allowed to rename your trait method foo to fooo?

If yes, please do and replace Foo::foo() with Foo:fooo() in your class method body before following static call syntax (by adding static keyword to your trait function definition)

```
<?php

trait Foo 
{
    protected static function Fooo()
    {
        echo 'Hello';
    }
}

class Bar 
{
    use Foo;

    private static function foo() 
    {
        self::fooo();

        echo ' World!';
    }

    public static function expose() 
    {
        echo self::foo();
    }
}

echo Bar::expose();
```

EDIT:

Obviously, the answer to my question was "No, you're not allowed to rename the trait method", for which case, you've pointed out a solution related to native conflict resolution embedded in PHP: 
http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.traits.php#language.oop5.traits.conflict